# Angular material tab group theme value set

Tags: angular, angular-material

Following the example from  [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples), changing the tabs theme with the toggle button works just fine. However, when I try setting the theme directly it does not work, here is the code:

```
<mat-tab-group [color]="accent" [backgroundColor]="primary">
    <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

When I use a property binding the value on the .ts file it does work:

```
...
tabsColor = 'accent';
tabsBackgroundColor = 'primary';
...

<mat-tab-group [color]="tabsColor" [backgroundColor]="tabsBackgroundColor">
    <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property `color` expects a string literal, but with the brackets you try to pass a variable called `accent`.

Try to change it to `color="accent"` without the brackets or `[color]="'accent'"`

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the color name inside `single quote ''` when you are using `double quote ""` outside, your code look like below :

```
<mat-tab-group [color]="'accent'" [backgroundColor]="'primary'">
    <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Even there is another way, you can use inline style like :

```
<mat-tab-group [style.color]="'accent'" [style.backgroundColor]="'primary'">
    <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```